# How to create modules in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: module

I am new on ExpressionEngine. I want to create a module from scratch can anyone help me out?

It will be a recruitment module which will first validate the email entered and then send a verification link to that email id.

And on click of that link the data will be fetched so that the user can update the result.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you've tried so far and what issues you're running into? I love to help but I'm not going to just do your job for you :p

Answer (score 3):

The 1st party guide is everything you need to get the concept of module/extension/add-on/plugin/fieldtype development : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html

If you're looking to hook into existing events refer to the list of hooks availabel and create an extension : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/

It looks to me like you don't need to do everything yourself as EE has a lot of what you want available. For instance you've described a classic Email sign up with a custom action on acceptance. You could use the registration system, with self verification via email, don't collect, set or otherwise set a passsword, when the user verifys registration hook the relivent event to do what you need, then put the 'signed up' user in a group that doesn't allow classic log in. This way the member system also acts as your information on who signed up, with what email and when, also who signed up but didn't validate...

Fill ya boots :D

Comment: I have gone through this link but m completely confused from where to start, can you please help me out in creating a module through code?

Comment: You're in massive danger of being too broad here mate, however I would go through the Module creation tutorial if your dead set on your own module, make the tutorial as then you'll have an example to play with. Is the idea of using the existing registration system not good enought? That way you'd need a light weight extension, not a heavy module, be easier to code for you too...